# Extract POJO values only if the key matches a criteria

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I want to extract only values assigned to keys which begin with the string "option". However, the .map() returns an array of object keys instead of their values.

```
var x = {

  one : 100,
  option1 : 'A', 
  option2 : 'B',
  opt : 'C'
}

var y = Object.keys(x).filter(key => {
  if (key.match(/^option\d*$/)) {
    return x[key]
  }
})

console.log(y) // returns ["option1", "option2"], should be ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: Have you confused filter and map? Filter will produce an array of items for which the given predicate function returns a truthy value. In your case you return the corresponding value for keys beginning with option, and the values happen to be truthy. You should first filter, then map the keys to values.

Comment: @IljaEverilä : Instead of using filter/map, one could just use reduce. That way you only iterate through the array once, not twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of filter. Filter uses the return value as a boolean to filter the original array, not create a new one.

```
var x = {
  one : 100,
  option1 : 'A', 
  option2 : 'B',
  opt : 'C'
}

var y = Object.keys(x).reduce((options, key) => {
  if (key.match(/^option\d*$/)) {
    options.push(x[key])
  }
  return options
}, [])

console.log(y) // returns ['A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

**array.map()** could help you this way :

```js
var x = {
  one : 100,
  option1 : 'A',
  option2 : 'B',
  opt : 'C'
}
var y = Object.keys(x).filter(key => key.match(/^option\d*$/)).map(key => x[key]);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: While this does work.. This is not an efficient way of list manipulation. This requires the list to be iterated through twice.

Comment: I really like this one but I agree with XerxesNoble that reduce is the simpler implementation. Many thanks for contributing